# Template and Hierarchy example from Stroustrup's C++ book

Tags: c++

Stroustrup uses the following example in C++ 4th Ed Page 768.  It appears to enter infinite recursion with `struct Node : Node_base<Node<Val>>`, `Node<Val>` depending on parent class `Node_base`, yet compiles ok.  Are my concerns about this founded?  How can this compile if this recursion is present?

I.e. I believe this recursion occurs `Derived : Base<Derived : Base<Derived : Base<Derived : Base …`

```
template<typename N>
struct Node_base {
    N* left_child;
    N* right_child;
    Node_base() {}
};

template<typename Val>
struct Node : Node_base<Node<Val>> {
    Val v;
    Node(Val vv) {v = vv;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Node<int> n{0};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like just a case of the curiously-recurring template pattern.  Is it not?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: That looks like it's it!

Comment: Does anyone know why the template system doesn't enter infinite recursion with this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

> I believe this recursion occurs Derived : Base<Derived : Base<Derived : Base<Derived : Base …

Well you can write out what actually happens without the placeholder names, by instantiating the templates into concrete types:

1. writing `Node<int>` starts instantiating a concrete class from the template, call it `Node_int`
2. `struct Node_int : Node_base<Node_int> { ... };` implicitly instantiates `Node_base_Node_int`
3. `struct Node_base_Node_int` has no further implicit instantiations - it doesn't depend on any other `Node<T>`, or indeed anything else at all. `Node_int` is already ... let's say *forward-declared* at this point, so the left and right child pointers are fine.

Note that if instantiating `Node_base<T>` used an *instance* of `T` as a member, you'd have a problem. But that's not because of recursion, it's because you haven't really finished instantiating it yet, so don't know the size. Using `T*` is fine in the same way that you can use pointers to any other forward-declared type.

NB. these concrete type names I used don't really exist. It's just to make it clear that eg. `Node<int>` is a concrete class and no longer a template.

Comment: I'm getting confused where `struct Node_int : Node_base<Node_int>` and `Node_int` also known as `Node<Val>` is declared as `struct Node : Node_base<Node<Val>>`.  Thats where I think the recursion is happening.  Perhaps I'm missing something about template instantiation?

Comment: In other words, I'm thinking that `Node<Val>` which is declared in `struct Node : Node_base<Node<Val>>`, is going to expand to this declaration again.

Comment: @notaorb: It's important to note that `Node_base` only deals with pointers and references to `N`, and never actually deals with `N` directly.  So `Node_base` only needs the name/declaration of a class, and it works fine, even if the class isn't defined yet.  So `struct Node :` declares the name of a struct, then `: Node_base<Node<Val>>` creates a full Node_base using that name/declaration, even though the class issn't defined yet.  After that, the `Node` class finishes being defined.

Comment: I could probably write the full thing out explicitly, forward declaration and everything ... but I'm beginning to think I've written it once before.

Comment: Where I'm getting confused is where `Node<Val>` is passed as an argument to `Node_base<Node<Val>>`.  My original thinking was `Node<Val>` instantiates `struct Node : Node_base<Node<Val>>`, then the instantiation happens again, hence my suspicion of infinite recursion.  I suspect this is not an instantiation in the argument?

Comment: @MooingDuck I think I understand it now.  `Node<Val>` is passed as an argument to `Node_base` parameter `T` and it is not instantiated.  It is simply a type.  Then it is used as a pointer to the type, which does not cause instantiation.

Comment: @notaorb Exactly! It's only a name/declaration.  This only works as long as `Node_base` limits itself to pointers and references in it's class definition, as those don't need the full type.  (Methods can contain more, but those are instantiated much much later)

Answer (score -1):

It does not enter infinite recursion because `Node` *inherits* `Node_base`, it's not identical to it. They are just two types that are somehow related, but to instantiate any one of them you don't need to have it instantiated.

You wouldn't be able to write `template<class Val> using Node = Node_base<Node<Val>>;`.

Comment: Still confused on this.  Is it because when `Node<Val>` is used as an argument to `Node_base` the derived part of the declaration of `Node`, `Node_base<Node<Val>>`, is not considered yet?